# azure ML studio terrible performance

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

the last day or two Azure ML studio performance is terrible.

It can take up to 10 mins to save a simple experiment and another 10 mins to run it.

These are simple tutorial experiments, nothing massive, using at maximum 18mb of data.

When i finally get the experiment to run and try to view the evaluation results, ML Studio spins for 5 mins before giving the error "Error producing the visualization of the output "

Note this error also occasionally occurs when i am just trying to view the list of saved experiments.

Im in the process of completing the Microsoft data science professional course and this is completely blocking me from making any progress.

Any info on what might be wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: If it's just something in the past day or two, as you said, then it could be a transient issue. Maybe ask tech support (via ticket, twitter, etc)?

Comment: Might be a problem with the region your ML workspace exists. Try moving the experiment to a different tenant and give a try if the problem bothers you for a long time.